# Chrome Apps Developer Tool for app on Android gives error: unable to launch server

Tags: android, google-chrome-app, chrome-app-developer-tool

I'm trying to install and run my Chrome App on Android (KitKat). I installed https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/harness/releases/ and then entered in the URL of my local server that has the crx file (and chose "crx file"): `http://192.168.1.102/mycrx.crx` but it won't get past the screen. It just says unable to launch server.

Comment: Chrome App Developer Tool is going through a lot of changes right now to make this flow a lot easier. May we start by clarifying which version you are using?

Comment: @mmocny I installed v0.4.2-alpha.